# I want know what are the query fired to cassandra during last 1 hour. Is there a way to get it?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh, kong

I want know what are the query fired to cassandra during last 1 hour.
I am using cassandra for kong. I am migrating kong 0.14.1 to kong 1.4.
I am running kong command over cassandra db as "kong migration up".
I want to know what are the operation kong is doing with cassandra.
Is there a way to get it?

Comment: can run `nodetool toppartitions`  around the time to see partition (and slowest queries after 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1. Log queries on the server side, with something like, [ecAudit](https://github.com/Ericsson/ecaudit), or [audit functionality in not yet released Cassandra 4.0](http://cassandra.apache.org/blog/2018/10/29/audit_logging_cassandra.html).
2. Log on the Kong side, although it could be a problem (I'm not Lua expert). But as I see in the source code, you can at least get log messages when [preparing queries](https://github.com/thibaultcha/lua-cassandra/blob/master/lib/resty/cassandra/cluster.lua#L777).